# How can I force a DiagnosticAnalyzer to refresh or reanalyze when a related document changes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a DiagnosticAnalyzer that reports parameters used in code that do not exist in a related json document.

But when the user adds the parameter to the related json document, the C# code file still has the diagnostic error in it. To refresh it manually I can add a space to the code file, and then the diagnostic error goes away.

I have a reference to the Document and I know when the test case json changes, but I'm not sure how to let the analyzer reanalyze the code when I think it should.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.